# Windows 7 reports mDNSResponse.exe caused a problem with Bonjour

Tags: windows, bonjour

Windows 7 Action Ceenter reports:

> Address a problem with Bonjour
>
> Bonjour has stopped working properly.
>
> The name of the file that caused this
>   problem is mDNSResponse.exe.
>
> For information about possible
>   solutions to this problem, go online
>   to the following Knowledge Base (KB)
>   article:
>
> Click to go online to the Apple Inc. website for the KB article

When clicked, the browser opens to the Bonjour Print Services for Windows download page.

One could infer this means "Download and reinstall Bonjour Print Services for Windows."  Is that what we are supposed to do?

All messages in the Event Viewer where the source is Bonjour Service are of severity *Informational*.  They alternate between *Service Started* and *Service Stopped(0)*.  My guess is the (0) is the return value.

I am asking here rather than some other stack because the malfunctioning software is a Windows executable authored and controlled by Apple.  When an application experiences a problem, it is the application which has the first responsibility for diagnosing and reporting the problem.  The operating system is responsible for faithfully executing the services the application requests, but it is unreasonable to expect the operating system to explain to a user why exactly an application ended abnormally.  Thus, this is an Apple issue, not a Windows issue.

After reinstallation of Bonjour, the problem was no longer reported.  However, that does not mean the reinstallation was fix; it could be that the problem is transient.

Comment: Hmmm, Apple software on Windows question. I guess the "Apple Software" part defines the fact that you posted it here?

Comment: Altough this about Apple software, you might have better luck posting on Super User.

Comment: @VxJaxonxV, I post here because people on the Apple stack are more likely to have experience with Bonjour than people on the SuperUser stack.  One of the current top Bonjour questions on SuperUser is "Do I need this software for any reason?"

Comment: @Thomas L Holaday - This is indeed Apple software however, the error itself is probably in some way related to the Windows OS.  Did you try re-installing?  Apparently Win 7 is much better about permissions however, I saw this a tonne on XP/Vista, and usually the process was not running with the right credentials.  Also; are there any entries about it in the event log?

Comment: Please provide some more info taken from the Event Log of Windows, otherwise this is virtually impossible to diagnose.

Comment: @Martin, the event log contains only informational messages from Bonjour; I added them to my question.

Comment: @Harv, I did not want to reinstall blindly, and since the error message contained a searchable string (mDNSResponse.exe) I wanted to get the answer into Apple Stack Exchange.

Comment: Are you actually trying to do anything with Bonjour?  Like print from win->mac or mac->win?  iTunes?  I try to avoid using Bonjour if I can -- it is unreliable in my experience.  I usually go by IP as much as I can.

Comment: @JoshHibschman, I conjecture that iTunes uses Bonjour to enable AirPlay & library sharing.  I do not recall installing Bonjour Print Services prior to the appearance of the mDNSResponse.exe complaint, so maybe the iTunes Bonjour installation is not quite the same as the Print Services Bonjour installation.

Comment: Same here it looks like mDNSResponse.exe from bonjour is causing problem in windows the firewall and antivirus are set to trusted software so theres something else beside windows os its a program using the same port or code line, like printers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared the problem on my system by reinstalling Bonjour.